# Is there a systematic way for figuring out wether a limit of multi-variables exists.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Searching through many books it does not seem clear to me how to figure out, without guessing and checking, wether limits do not exist. I know about the method of paths, and my professor told us to begin by attempting to set up a solution by squeeze theorem, as it may help us choose a path or may help us prove the limit exists. But it does not always work. Is their a systematic way to choose a path to show a multivariable limit DNE?

Comment: I don't think your question has a good answer. To me,  the question is along the line of determining whether a series would converge. Well, you try a bunch of tricks. If it fails then you probably have to try harder.

Answer (score 1):

You come up with some distance metric.  The Euclidean norm is a good one. Square of the Euclidean norm.  The 
"taxi-cab" norm i.e. $(|x_1|+|x_2|\cdots|x_n|)$.  Sometimes it depends on the limit to decide which metric use.

If you are looking at a limit approaching $(0,0)$, converting to polar coordinates is handy, because it is something that you know how to do.  When you do so,$r$ is the distance to $(0,0)$.

However you define distance, you will need to show that $d(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)<\delta \implies d(f(\mathbf x),f(\mathbf y))<\epsilon$

Comment: My question is how do I show that. Different limits might use different tricks, but is their a systematic way. Also, really my main question is how do I pick the paths.

Comment: Picking paths is a great way to show that a limit does not exist.  And, $y=Kx$ is always good.  But, it does not definitively prove that a limit does exist.

Comment: If $y=kx$ does not help we pick a different path, but we guess. How can we pick a right path without guessing?

Comment: If y=kx does not show that the limit does not exist, then I would not suggest you keep picking paths.  I would suggest you try to define the appropriate distance measure.